# Não consigo "recuperar" o valor da Realtime Database (Firebase)

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

Eu estou tentando isso, mas sempre aparece que o app parou de funcionar.

```
public class TesteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView la;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teste);


        la = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtavisoteste);

        DatabaseReference dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuario");

        dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                la.setText(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(TesteActivity.this, "Erro: " + error.toException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual valor você quer obter? Ali ele vai tentar retornar o valor de usuário, porém se tiver nulo pode acontecer um NullPointerException.

```
dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final String value;
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString != null){
                   value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                   //Eu prefiro usar assim ou String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                   //Mas lembre-se de que o valor gravado sempre sera uma string para evitar exceções futuras.
                } else { value = "String com valor nulo"; }
                la.setText(value);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(TesteActivity.this, "Erro: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Aqui também para ver o erro você poderia usar um log, acredito que fica melhor para ver o erro na hora de testar o app e tudo mais.
                //Log.i("TAG", error.getMessage()); 
            }
        });
```